# How to configure Web Service for creating Web Service Class 1 time

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I have a `Book.class`:

```
public class Book{
   private String title;

   public String getTitle() {
      if(title == null){
         title = "not found";
      }
      return title;
   }

   public void setTitle(String title) {
      this.title = title;
   }

}
```

And `services.xml` for configuration Web Service:

```
 <service name="StockQuoteService">
    <Description>
        Please Type your service description here
    </Description>
    <messageReceivers>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only"
                         class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver"/>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"
                         class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
    </messageReceivers>
    <parameter name="ServiceClass">sample.StockQuoteService</parameter>
</service>
```

When I start web service, I want to set new book title and get this title. But when I get this new title, I have always `null`. This is because instance of Books class created every time, when I send request. How to configure this Web Service for: set title `Hello` and get title `Hello`?

StockQuoteService:

```
package sample;

public class StockQuoteService {

   private Book book = new Book();

   public void setBook(Book book){
      this.book = book;
   }

   public String getTitle(){
      return book.getTitle();
   }

}
```

Comment: The question is not very clear, but as far as I understand, if you want to have just one instance of Book, you could use the 
[singleton](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html) pattern.

Comment: @lateralus I remembered about this pattern. But I think, that there is some other way for configuration.

Comment: Can you post your sample.StockQuoteService class also

Comment: @JSIK already posted.

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Make sure you set book's title at the web service client class before calling the service. Other than that, cannot see any issue here.  If you can, post your client class where you create book object and call the web service's setBook() method

Answer (score 0):

To avoid creating new object every time, you have to use LifeCycle in Axis2 and store your Book instance in Axis2 Context. Follow below steps to do that.

1. Do not create new Book instance in StockQuoteService class. Just  declare the variable as

   ```
   private Book book;
   ```
2. Change StockQuoteService class to implement Lifecycle interface of axis2 (org.apache.axis2.service.Lifecycle).
3. With above change, you have to implement below two methods in your class.

   ```
   public void init (ServiceContext serviceContext){

      ConfigurationContext configurationContext =
           MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext()
           .getConfigurationContext();

      if (configurationContext != null) {
           book = new Book();
           configurationContext.setProperty("SERVICE_BOOK", book);
      }
   }

   public void destroy(ServiceContext serviceContext) {    
   }
   ```
4. By doing this, it does not create new Book instance at every service call. Instead, it will create Book instance at service start up (init method is called only at service start up), and store the book variable in the configuration context.